# addr is of illegal length

Tags: java

I am checking whether the ipAddress is in Private Category or not. So I wrote this method below. And I am getting this as an exception-

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: addr is of illegal length
    at java.net.InetAddress.getByAddress(InetAddress.java:948)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getByAddress(InetAddress.java:1324)
```

ipAddress (172.18.36.81) is String

```
if(isPrivateIPAddress(ipAddress)) {

            return null;
        }


private static boolean isPrivateIPAddress(String ipAddress) {

    byte[] byteArray = null;
    InetAddress ia = null;
    try {
        byteArray = ipAddress.getBytes("UTF-16LE");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }


    try {
        ia = InetAddress.getByAddress(byteArray);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return ia.isSiteLocalAddress();
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `byteArray`?

Comment: `ipAddress.getBytes("UTF-16LE");`?

Comment: Have you tried outputting `byteArray` before passing it to `getByAddress`?

Comment: And how long is the ip address?

Comment: If I try printing I am getting [B@3a303a3.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you've misunderstood how to convert an IP address from `String` to `byte[]`. The proper way to do that is to parse `String` to a sequence of `int`s, and then cast each of those to a `byte`. But fortunately, `InetAddress` already has a method to handle that for you, so you can just write:

```
private static boolean isPrivateIPAddress(String ipAddress)
{
    return InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress).isSiteLocalAddress();
}
```

(together with whatever validity-checking and error-handling you want).

Note that the above will also handle hostnames, by using DNS lookup. If you don't want that, you'll need to pre-check the IP-address, using something like this:

```
if(! Pattern.matches("(\\d{1,3}\\.){3}\\d{1,3}", ipAddress)
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
```

if you're O.K. with only supporting IPv4.

Comment: ,Thanks for information. But I was not able to get your second part, handling **host names**, Can you explain that little bit.

Comment: @RaihanJamal: I'm saying that `InetAddress.getByName(String)` handles both IP addresses and hostnames; for hostnames, it looks up the name in [DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System). It seemed from your question that you might not want to do that DNS lookup, so I suggested a way to check to confirm that the string is an IP address (rather than a hostname) before calling that method.

Answer (score 1):

Internet addresses fed to this method must be in byte arrays that are either 4 or 16 bytes long.  Stop this in a debugger after your decoding and see how long it is; the exception is telling you it is not one of these two.  Then figure out how to fix the encoding.