# addr is of illegal length while converting string to byte

Tags: java, ping

I'm writing a mod for a game(minecraft), for a friend. to do the specified function of the mod I need to make sure a server is reachable within a certain time, I used InetAddress to do this but every time I use the command I get this error

```
2012-12-02 18:45:53 [INFO] [STDERR] java.net.UnknownHostException: addr is of illegal length
2012-12-02 18:45:53 [INFO] [STDERR]     at java.net.InetAddress.getByAddress(Unknown Source)
2012-12-02 18:45:53 [INFO] [STDERR]     at java.net.InetAddress.getByAddress(Unknown Source)
2012-12-02 18:45:53 [INFO] [STDERR]     at net.minecraft.src.CommandServSwitch.processCommand(CommandServSwitch.java:40)
2012-12-02 18:45:53 [INFO] [STDERR]     at net.minecraft.src.CommandHandler.executeCommand(CommandHandler.java:81)
2012-12-02 18:45:53 [INFO] [STDERR]     at net.minecraft.src.NetServerHandler.handleSlashCommand(NetServerHandler.java:715)
2012-12-02 18:45:53 [INFO] [STDERR]     at net.minecraft.src.NetServerHandler.handleChat(NetServerHandler.java:681)
2012-12-02 18:45:53 [INFO] [STDERR]     at net.minecraft.src.Packet3Chat.processPacket(Packet3Chat.java:60)
2012-12-02 18:45:53 [INFO] [STDERR]     at net.minecraft.src.MemoryConnection.processReadPackets(MemoryConnection.java:79)
2012-12-02 18:45:53 [INFO] [STDERR]     at net.minecraft.src.NetServerHandler.networkTick(NetServerHandler.java:82)
2012-12-02 18:45:53 [INFO] [STDERR]     at net.minecraft.src.NetworkListenThread.networkTick(NetworkListenThread.java:55)
2012-12-02 18:45:53 [INFO] [STDERR]     at net.minecraft.src.IntegratedServerListenThread.networkTick(IntegratedServerListenThread.java:111)
2012-12-02 18:45:53 [INFO] [STDERR]     at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.updateTimeLightAndEntities(MinecraftServer.java:696)
2012-12-02 18:45:53 [INFO] [STDERR]     at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.tick(MinecraftServer.java:592)
2012-12-02 18:45:53 [INFO] [STDERR]     at net.minecraft.src.IntegratedServer.tick(IntegratedServer.java:110)
2012-12-02 18:45:53 [INFO] [STDERR]     at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:499)
2012-12-02 18:45:53 [INFO] [STDERR]     at net.minecraft.src.ThreadMinecraftServer.run(ThreadMinecraftServer.java:17)
```

The method generating this error(and all the code you need to know):

```
    @Override
public void processCommand(ICommandSender var1, String[] var2) {
    if(var2.length < 1 || var2.length > 3) {
            throw new WrongUsageException("command.switch.usage", new Object[0]);
    }
    else {
             servport = Integer.parseInt(var2[1]);

            boolean ping = false;
            try {
                InetAddress IP = InetAddress.getByAddress(var2[0].getBytes());
                ping = IP.isReachable(400);
            } catch(UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: This [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9729842/addr-is-of-illegal-length) seems to address that exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs for [getByAddress](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getByName%28java.lang.String%29) say: "Returns an InetAddress object **given the raw IP address**. The argument is **in network byte order**: the highest order byte of the address is in getAddress()[0]."

```
            InetAddress IP = InetAddress.getByAddress(var2[0].getBytes());
```

This line of code doesn't make any sense. The string is not the raw IP address in network byte order as the function requires. Otherwise, it would be precisely four bytes long.

You need to call [InetAddress.getByName](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getByName%28java.lang.String%29) to convert from a text string, like `foo.domain.com` or `1.2.3.4` to internal binary format.

Comment: I should explain better, during testing the string I used was"173.242.126.66" var2[0] is the place the string is stored after a command is entered into the game. I've handled that exception and provided a message in later code if there was no server to be reached or addr is too long or short but in the case of the IP I used I have no clue.

Comment: +1 @DavidSchwartz is correct. To clarify, the _String_ value is **not** a network address.  An address passed to `getByAddress()` is a 4 byte array containing the IP address in network form. For example, if the String IP address is _"173.242.126.66"_, the byte array should contain `{0xAD, 0xF2, 0x7E, 0x42}`

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't read his full answer, I get it now thanks!